# loop over all directories and keep files alive

Tags: r, bash, touch, keep-alive

I have different directories on supercomputer and the issue is that all files will be deleted after a short time with no touch. Is there any command, library or function in R or bash (Preferably in R) to loop over all directories and keep files alive? (I don't want to update files)
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please tag sensibly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you have certain files which will be deleted if they are not modified within a set interval. You can just `touch` the files to prevent them being deleted. But that said, you need to add a `cron` job to automate the touching process. It can be as simple as

```
#!/bin/bash
#This script is named say touchscript.sh
#Your list of directories to deal with go below
dirlst=("/path/to/dir1" "/path/to/dir2")
for dirvalue in "${dirlist[@]}"
do 
find "$dirvalue" -type f -exec touch {} \;
done
```

And add a cronjob

```
0 * * * * /path/to/touchscript.sh
```

---

<sup>**Note:** `touchscript.sh` should be an executable ie do `chmod u+x` to that. Use `crontab -e` to add a cronjob and put the above in there</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the help